# Facebook API PHP Get The ID Of User's "Profile Pictures" Album

Tags: php, facebook

I would like to get all of the pictures from a user's "Profile Pictures" album on facebook.

However, I did not find any reference to selecting this album in [Facebook's Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs).

Do you have any idea on how to do that?

I've found the solution myself-run an fql query in the table "album" with type "profile".

[Facebook Developers FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you need to get permission from user. Such as user_photos permission. Once you permitted, you can retrieve user photos by FQL.

Comment: Correct-but as you can see i put the answer there myself.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer for this question wasn't helpful for me but here is the FQL that works for me:

```
SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = me() AND type = 'profile'
```

Keep in mind that an album has 2 types of IDs. There's the album id (aid) specific to the album and the object_id which is what you can use to identify the object from the Facebook Graph API.